# jquery and css code for an activity stream

Tags: jquery, css, feed, microblogging

I 've made a simple live message stream with node.js and socket.io
I use jquery's .prepend for every new message and with some simple html to look a little bit better on the browser, but I was wondering if there is an open source project for this that will make my life easier.
Something that would have a similar result with the facebook ticker, the twitter feed, etc.